# Design UIImages scrolling like circle animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, carousel

I would like to design the scrolling images like the image below. 
Could you please help me with this task?

[image: scrolling images]

Comment: use iCarosael for your concept

Comment: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel
refer this link

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik. is it possible to use iCarousel in UITableView. Please help me with that.

Comment: @ramraghav - we can use

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik . Please provide my working example for me. im unable to do that. Please ping to my mail id (raghava.dokala@gmail.com)

Comment: see this link you get idea https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/issues/409

Comment: okay.. Thank you. i will check and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use iCarousel to achieve the same effect.
Its an amazing third party library.
It can be easily implemented and works like a charm.
Implement methods defined in iCarouselDataSource protocol

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel;//Return the number of items (views) in the carousel.

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view; // return views for specific carousel.
```

iCarousel supports many built-in display types.
iCarouselTypeTimeMachine or iCarouselTypeInvertedTimeMachine display types matches your requirement.

There are many predefined properties of iCarousel with which you can play around and get the required result.

You can check iCarousel [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel).

Comment: Thank you @luckyShubhra. is it possible to use iCarousel in UITableView. Please help me with that.

Comment: I need to check for the same. I will let you know.

Comment: I followed above steps. but i have struck at displaying it in UITableView. Please help

Comment: ok. Thank You for your time @luckyShubhra. If you get solution please ping to my mail id (raghava.dokala@gmail.com).

Comment: I really dont think so its impossible. You can make your custom cell and delegate that cell as icarousel delegate as well as iCarousel datasource. Inside your custom cell implemnt delegated and datasource methods of icarousel.

Comment: I will provide you full working code afterwards.

Comment: ok . Thank you. please send it to my mail id.